# Cannot import Maven project in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have tried to import existing **Maven Project** into **Eclipse** but this error occurs (as shown in image):

[image]

I use **Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers**, Version: Mars.2 Release (4.5.2).

When I go to Window > Preferences > Maven, then also this error occurs:

> Unable to create the selected preference page.
>   An error occurred while automatically activating bundle org.eclipse.m2e.core.ui (1018).

I don't know what to do, please help!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To resolve the issue, we recommend installing a brand-new version of Eclipse. If you don't have the archive available, simply download it again. After that, proceed to reimport the project and you should be all set.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a strange problem with Eclipse installation. Try to install a refresh copy of Eclipse (try to download again if you don't have the archive) and reimport the project.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Yes I uninstalled eclipse, then installed it, now it works fine. Thank you